# How to create output table using given input using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, output, tabular

If you were given the following input:

8, Black, Lexus
9, Green, Mercedes
10, Brown, Cadillac
11, Gray, Porsche

What would be the proper procedure to get the output forming a table where the headers are: id, Color, Car

Comment: and how is the input given?

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz it is typed in as the example above

Answer (score 1):

You create a `table` element and start to append the `header` elements and after the body rows like below.

```js
//create Table
var table = document.createElement('table');

//create Table Header
var header = ['Id', 'Color', 'Car' ];
var tr=document.createElement('tr');
for(var column in header)
{   
  var th=document.createElement('th');
  th.innerHTML = header[column];
  tr.appendChild(th)
}
table.appendChild(tr);

//create Table Body
var input = [
  [8, 'Black', 'Lexus'],
  [9, 'Green', 'Mercedes'], 
  [10, 'Brown', 'Cadillac'],
  [11, 'Gray', 'Porsche']
];

for(var row in input)
{
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var column in input[row]){
      
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = input[row][column];
        tr.appendChild(td)
        
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

// append Table
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="carid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Color:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="color">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Car </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="car">
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="adddata()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
function adddata() { 

    var cid = document.getElementById("carid");
    var ccolor = document.getElementById("color");
    var ccar = document.getElementById("car");

    var table = document.getElementById("dymanictable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= cid.value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= ccolor.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= ccar.value;

}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/vvL43hy3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check http://fiddle.jshell.net/5or3sLg5/2/

You must get data in an array and replace for-loop limits:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
```

Must be something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.lenght; i++){
```

And where to get the data

```
var text1 = document.createTextNode('8');
var text2 = document.createTextNode('Black ');
var text3 = document.createTextNode('Lexus');
```

must be something like

```
var text1 = document.createTextNode(data[i,1]);
var text2 = document.createTextNode(data[i,2]);
var text3 = document.createTextNode(data[i,3]);
```